# Facebook Object Debugger problems with GeoPoint

Tags: facebook-graph-api, object

Why does the Facebook object debugger report `Missing required property`, when a property is set?

The Facebook object is this: http://www.spotcracy.com/fbspotobj.php.

The debugger reports that the `spotcracy:location` is not present but, under the object property is it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Its another sensless mistake of FB interface.
Uncheck "Is Required" option for spotcracy at FB app opengraph admin panel. Error message will gone and functionality will not be affected.
So its allowed to set "Is Required" for custom geopoint object but it leads to no good but errors. If you will try to provide any content for such "required" object it will knock out debugger.